# Gauge field and Lie group

Tags: gauge-theory, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra

I'm studying $SU(N)$ gauge theory, but I'm confused.

Here([Gauge fields -- why are they traceless hermitian?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/67792/gauge-fields-why-are-they-traceless-hermitian)), the reason why  a gauge field is in the Lie algebra of a gauge group $G$ is that we have to cancel out the term which comes from the kinetic term by acting gauge transformation.

For simplification I want to use the $F_{\mu \nu}$. I know this transforms as
$$
F_{\mu \nu} \to gF_{\mu\nu}g^{-1}
$$
and it's called adjoint representation ($g\in G$). However, is it true that $F_{\mu \nu}$ belongs to the Lie algebra, just because it undergoes a change as an adjoint representation? In my understanding, adjoint representation means that an element of a certain set $x\in X$ changes
$$
Ad(g)x=gxg^{-1}
$$
and then $x$ does not have to be in $G$. For example we can show this act becomes representation: $Ad(g_1)Ad(g_2)=Ad(g_1g_2)$, even if $x\notin G$.

Anyway, my question is:

Why the adjoint representation has the important role for $A_{\mu}, F_{\mu \nu}\in$ (Lie algebra of $G$)?

Comment: The important thing is that $A_\mu$ is a Lie-algebra valued one-form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field strength $F_{\mu \nu}$ is a (local representation of) a Lie-algebra valued two-form. In components, it is often written as $F_{\mu \nu}^a$, where the $\mu \nu$ are the space-time indices (making it a two-form) and a is the Lie-algebra index. As such, it is indeed in the Lie-algebra.

However, it is not any Lie-algebra valued two form. Instead, it is the (local representation of) the covariant derivative of a special one-form, the connection one-form (whose local representation is usually denoted by $A_{\mu}$). This necessarily transforms in the adjoint representation. An intuitive reasoning for this can be found in [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/462723/why-quarks-in-the-fundamental-and-gluons-in-the-adjoint) (1).

This is the mathematical viewpoint. The physical viewpoint is that the adjoint rep gives the "correct" transformation, simply because of the way we have defined the field strength in non-abelian gauge theories. Specifically, the field strength is defined as (this definition comes from the differential geometry picture sketched above):
$$
F_{\mu \nu} = \partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}-\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}-i[A_{\nu},A_{\mu}] 
$$
And if you perform a gauge transformation of this object (as is done e.g. [here](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/pdf/10.1142/9789813234192_0001) (2), you find that it transforms in the adjoint representation.

(1)[Why quarks in the fundamental and gluons in the adjoint?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/462723/why-quarks-in-the-fundamental-and-gluons-in-the-adjoint)
(2)https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/pdf/10.1142/9789813234192_0001